# Why doesn't this ajax call to Controller work in a particular page (Laravel)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

There is an Ajax call that works on other pages, but not on the very page I want to use it. Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var city = "مشهد";
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET', 
            url: '/changecredsgrabdata', 
            data: {id : city}, 
            success: function(response){
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        });
</script>
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/changecredsgrabdata', 'LoginController@placeholders');
```

And here is the controller method:

```
public function placeholders(Request $req) {
    $qer = $req->id;
    $user_id = SESSION::get('user_id'); //GETTING USER ID
    foreach($user_id as $key=>$item){
        $user_id[$key]= (array)$item;
    }
    $user_id = $user_id[0]["user_id"];  /////////////////

    $user_data = DB::select 
    ('SELECT user_mail ,user_firstname, user_family, user_mobile FROM app_users WHERE user_id= ?' , [$user_id]);
    return response()->json($user_data);
}
```

The ajax works in other pages, also $user_data isn't empty and is exactly what I want. 
I also passed an id of city and used it on the first line of my method, but I don't need any data to be sent at all and I only sent it because I didn't know how not to send any data. so ignore that bit.

Comment: Are you logged in when you're on this page?

Comment: I am. when I replace return view with  echo (SESSION::get('loggedin')) I get a "1", meaning I am logged in.

Comment: Do the other pages still work when you're logged in?

Comment: they do work when logged in.

Comment: The problems seems to be with ajax only. when I redirect to the same method of LoginController  and dd($user_data) it shows alright.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution and I can't believe to have made such stupid mistake. I didn't add jQuery. So I added a simple line in the head of html and the problem is solved. Here's the line of code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```